# Xcode 4, subproject import problem

Tags: xcode, project-organization

I want to add a project as a subproject. When I drag the subproject into the main project it appears as a file reference rather than subproject. The picture below explains the problem:

[image: Xcode subproject import problem]

Comment: Just curious, what's the advantage of doing that?

Comment: @David It makes it easy to share code and organise code. In the above example expressionTest could contain a static library that could be used in Content and other projects. Development of ExpressionTest can occur independently of Content and all changes will be automatically available to Content.

Comment: I've been looking for a similar idea, but doesn't it clutter your main project?

Comment: @David Not really. Ultimately the main projects needs to include all the code. I keep subprojects and the static libraries they generate in their own group. Subprojects  contain all their related test code and demo apps, which reduces the amount of code in the main project. Getting it set up is a bit tricky, but once you've done you really appreciate it. I've set up a subproject that creates a bundle containing the nib files and images etc (there'll be over 100 nibs when the apps finished). The designer can work with this subproject and not worry about breaking code.

Comment: Another benefit of subprojects is that it reduces the occurrences of the contents of the .xcproject needing to be merged. Merging the .xcproject is painful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The solution is to ensure that the subproject is not open. Once the project is closed Xcode can add the project as a subproject.

Comment: I couldn't believe it but once I closed my subproject and went to add it to the main project it worked. Thanks!

Comment: ZOMG! I struggled with this Googling left and right to no avail and BAM! this solved it! It's hard to believe that XCode believes in this way!

Comment: Just ran into the same exact issue on xcode 6.0.1. I wish xcode actually told me what the issue was instead of just deciding not to import the file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple.Just close that project and again open that project then you'll get that subproject.I too faced this problem so I did like this.